# Ordering results (from a search) by number of matches

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-order-by

I'm implementing search for an Android app using an SQLite db, and am wanting to order the results from a search according to the number of matches in a TEXT column

For example let's say that my db table is called `article`, the TEXT column I want to search is called `article_main_text`, and that the the user searches for the word "friend". Then I want the db table rows which have the highest number of occurrences of "friend" in their `article_main_text` column to be shown first

I already know that I can provide custom SQLite statements in the sort order in my CursorLoader (for example supplying this to the CursorLoader constructor), so I'd like to ask: *How can I write SQLite code that orders the results with the help of SQLite?*

Answer (score 1):

Counting just the occurrences of a word might not be the most accurate or most efficient way of doing it. What you really need is full text search. Which is [supported in sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) and available in Android.

Fortunately there is a tutorial on [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html) and I am sure there would be a full working sample in their code collections.

Comment: i've found a way to count the number of occurances (that's the specification i got) but am still struggling though with how to get all of this into Android